# How can return linq to sql query result in c# web service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm beginner in web service and want to write web service return linq to sql query result,write this code:

```
DataClasses1DataContext behzad = new DataClasses1DataContext(conn);

string result;
var query = (from p in behzad.CDRTABLEs
             where p.name == "behzad".Trim()
             select p).Take(1);

return query.ToString();
```

but return to me this:
[image]

but i want return table data not linq to sql query,how can i solve that?

when i change `return query.ToString();` `to return query;` i get this error:
[image]

Comment: Well, don't call `ToString()` on it ... :)

Comment: @Rob update my question please review

Comment: You need to change your method to return `IQueryable<CDRTABLE>` in that case. Or a `List<CDRTABLE>` and replace `ToString()` with `ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the object of the result you need to create a class and then return it. So first create a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then do the query like this:

```
var behzad = new DataClasses1DataContext(conn);

var query = (from p in behzad.CDRTABLEs
             where p.name == "behzad".Trim()
             select new Foo
             {
                Id=p.Id,
                Name=p.Name
             }).FirstOrDefault();

return query;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `ToString-ing` the query, rather than the result. Since you are using `Take` to get one result, you can use `FirstOrDefault` to evaluate the query and return the first result, or `NULL` if there isn't any.

```
var result = (from p in behzad.CDRTABLEs
                     where p.name == "behzad".Trim()
                     select p).FirstOrDefault();

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute your query - call FirstOrDefault():

```
    var query = (from p in behzad.CDRTABLEs
                 where p.name == "behzad".Trim()
                 select p).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: return me this:<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">DATATYTPEWEBSERVICE.CDRTABLE</string>

Comment: If you need to get Id: return query.Id.ToString(); or if you want to get all data you should call: var query = (...).ToList();